# IIS express return 500 error for js or css

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

My css and  js don't load when i load my local website and iis returns error with code 500.
I use asp.net mvc 5, VS 2013 update 4, iis express insight Visual studio.
then i use https for web project.

I have tried to add in web.config

remove fileExtension=".woff" 
mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff"

but it have not helped

Also Page loads good, but references in page to js and css don't load.
And If I replace local path to external(e.g  "/Scripts/angular.js" to "https://ajax.googleapis.com/../angular.js") all work ok.

screen with error page: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5YzS.png)

my web.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="CloudTruck.WebApi" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Any more details? 500 is an internal server error, usually it'll tell you more on the error page (like bad config)?

Comment: added eroor's printscreen .

Comment: I suppose your problem have nothing with `js` or `css` files. Your problem in `Web.Config` or in `cs`  files. Show your `Web.Config` and tell us more.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have a remote developer experiencing the exact same issue, and I can't replicate it.